# AutoMapper 5 when set CreateMissingTypeMaps true ForMember not work

Tags: entity-framework-6, automapper-5

I think I found the cause of the problem, but I don't know how to solve it,
the scene is like this:

i used automapper 5.2 , Entity Framework 6 and use `CreateMissingTypeMaps=true` to save my CreateMap code
and i also have special map, so Initialize code like this

```
 Mapper.Initialize(
            a =>
                {
                    a.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
                    a.CreateMap<query_template, QtGridUdfSearchTemplate>()
               .ForMember(dest => dest.GridId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GRID_ID))
               .ForMember(dest => dest.Guid, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.QUERY_TEMPLATE_GUID))
               .ForMember(dest => dest.TemplateName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TEMPLATE_NAME))
               .ForMember(dest => dest.CreatedBy, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CREATED_BY))
               .ForMember(dest => dest.IsDefault, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.IS_DEFAULT))
               .ForMember(dest => dest.IsOffset, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.IS_OFFSET));
                }
         );
```

and map code

```
 var source = DbContext.Set<query_template>().Find(keyValue);
 var dest = Mapper.Map<query_template, QtGridUdfSearchTemplate>(source);
```

i get the `dest` all attribute is null ,when i remove `a.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;` in Initialize , it is work , the `dest` all attribute can be map.

then i found the `source` Type is `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.query_template_80DE6B32EB08D5DFDD560580BB004DAD6A7FF27B94A3517A6BB4044B01FB8272` , so i think when i set CreateMissingTypeMaps , autoMapper auto create a map , not my create

many posts suggested `context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;` but i use LazyLoad. and don`t want to remove CreateMissingTypeMaps , because i have many normal type to map .

anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting `ForMember(...)`, try:

```
ForMember<ObjectThatYouWantMap>(*Expression*);
```

Comment: thanks Jorge ,  it is not work for me ,  i also ask in gitHub ,  https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1954 , that means Don't use CreateMissingTypeMaps unless you don't know the types at run time